# Download PDF from Blade File do not show letters Ć, Č, Ž

Tags: css, laravel, pdf, utf-8

I am a beginner in PHP.
I have a problem when I generate pdf for download I cannot see special characters in the Croatian language (Č, Ć, Š). The problem is present only on that preview for download. I have changed all the fields in DB to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. 
[image]

File for pdf preview:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            background: inherit;
            font-size: 14px;
        },
        .tbl-total {
            width: inherit;
            border: 0;
        }
        .tbl-total th, .tbl-total tr, .tbl-total td {
            border: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> tag?

Comment: By definition PDF format's goal is to maintain fidelity of a document. It does that by storing fonts inside the document itself. If you can't see some characters, then either: 1) the PDF was badly generated (excluding fonts), 2) It was processed afterwards and lost features, or 3) you are using a defective PDF viewer. I can't see any other reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding CSS property inside the `style` `body` tag

```
font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
```